# TestNG Runner class ignores tests

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, testng

I Am running my test cases via TestNG runner class,but the problem is when there is only 1 class in runner class all tests are executed correctly.
correct execution xml
[image: Correct execution XML]
Whereas if There are more than 1 classes in runner class I get ignored Test cases and suite runs only 1 test cases(method) only from both classes .
[image: Incorrect Xml execution]
Can someone please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@Test(alwaysRun = true)` , For before methods (`beforeSuite`, `beforeTest`, `beforeTestClass` and `beforeTestMethod`, but not `beforeGroups`): If set to true, this configuration method will be run regardless of what groups it belongs to.
For after methods (`afterSuite`, `afterClass`, ...): If set to true, this configuration method will be run even if one or more methods invoked previously failed or was skipped.

Comment: This Approach worked but Partially.
Now more than one tests run, but problem is they are executed alphabetically not in specific order which previously I had set as @Test(Priority='sequential numbers').
Hence 1 thing I can pre assume is that issue was related to @Priority Thing.
But why it is issue still a question also how can I fix my issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Arun
I did run some more tests on the same and below solution worked.
I had provided same `@priority` number to different test cases in different test classes, which confused the XML file maybe and it ran only 1 test case from both.
I changed sequential priorities like 1-4 then in next class 4-9(5 Tcases).It worked
However still not sure why test ng didn't gave any error message for the same and just passed as test cases ignored.